# SQL LAG Function and Grouping/Ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following table:

```sh
    +--------------------------------------------------+
    |                        Users                     |                  
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |acc_num| user_id |   date   |  amount  |    sum   |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |   null   |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |          |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |          |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |    50    |        Correct
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |          |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |          |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I want to calculate the sum based on today and the previous day as you see above. I am using the LAG function since I am on Postgres. However, even though I am grouping and ordering based acc_num, user_id and date, but when the new sum column is added, the value is sometimes 60 and sometimes 50. So sometimes I get the above result and sometimes I get the results below:

```sh
    +--------------------------------------------------+
    |                        Users                     |                  
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |acc_num| user_id |   date   |  amount  |    sum   |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |   null   |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |          |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |          |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |          |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |    60    |        Wrong
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |          |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

or I get this:

```sh
    +--------------------------------------------------+
    |                        Users                     |                  
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |acc_num| user_id |   date   |  amount  |    sum   |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |   null   |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |          |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20201209 |    20    |          |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |          |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |          |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20201208 |    30    |    60    |        Wrong
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Now my SQL is similar to this:

```sql
    SELECT acc_num, user_id, date
      (CASE 
        WHEN (amount > 0) 
        THEN LAG(amount, 1) OVER (ORDER BY acc_num, user_id, date) + amount 
        ELSE NULL 
        END
      ) AS sum
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY acc_num, user_id, date
    ORDER BY acc_num, user_id, date
```

I have also tried:

```sql
    SELECT acc_num, user_id, date
      (CASE 
        WHEN (amount > 0) 
        THEN LAG(amount, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date) + amount 
        ELSE NULL 
        END
      ) AS sum
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY acc_num, user_id, date
    ORDER BY acc_num, user_id, date
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have multiple rows with the same values?

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with `lead`, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o1VDH5kCJAQU5kyjB2nKM9/0).

```
select
    acc_num, 
    user_id, 
    date, 
    amount,
    sum(case when (nm is not null and amount <> nm) then nm + amount end) over (partition by acc_num, user_id) as sum 
from
(
    select
        *,
        lead(amount) over (order by date) as nm
    from myTable
) t
```

output:

```
| acc_num | user_id | date     | amount | sum |
| ------- | ------- | -------- | ------ | --- |
| a1      | u1      | 20201209 | 20     |     |
| a1      | u1      | 20201209 | 20     |     |
| a1      | u1      | 20201209 | 20     |     |
| a1      | u2      | 20201208 | 30     | 50  |
| a1      | u2      | 20201208 | 30     | 50  |
| a1      | u2      | 20201208 | 30     | 50  |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want exactly one value from the previous *day*.  That is a bit tricky for a couple of reasons, but very importantly, because you have no stable numbering of the rows -- that is, there are duplicates.

I would suggest:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(date) over (order by seqnum) < date
             then amount + lag(amount) over (order by seqnum)
        end)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date, acc_num, user_id) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
order by seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=832683cef378e2d39728d0488902e029) is a db<>fiddle.

If you wanted this on all three rows, you could use `last_value()` with a `range` window frame as well:

```
select t.*,
       amount + last_value(amount) over (order by date range between unbounded preceding and interval '1 day' preceding)
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already was implementing with the earlier answer and it work. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: @Stacky . . . Your question asks for the value on a single row, not all three rows, which is why I provided an answer.